# Wordpress security, how to disable wp user_id 0

Tags: wordpress, security

I have a WordPress website that I installed with the Stream plugin (to check website activity), i found something when i search for suspicious activity, here the screenshoot [image: user id 0 is updated some other user]

some times ago our site have been infected by malware, I've tried to clean it up and install security plugins and firewall, but now, some of our user data is being updated by someone(or user) with id 0 (yeah, i check it on stream plugin, that user has user_id of 0)

is that anything i can do for disable that user or detect which user has compromised password?

here's my plugin list

```
Admin Menu Editor   Version 1.11 by Janis Elsts | Auto-updates disabled
BEAF - Ultimate Before After Image Slider & Gallery Version 4.3.15 by Themefic | Auto-updates disabled
Custom links in Elementor Image Carousel    Version 1.1.1 by Charlie Etienne | Auto-updates disabled
Elementor   Version 3.13.2 by Elementor.com | Auto-updates disabled
Element Pack Lite - Addons for Elementor    Version 4.8.0 by BdThemes | Auto-updates disabled
Essential Addons for Elementor  Version 5.7.2 by WPDeveloper | Auto-updates disabled
Essential Blocks    Version 4.0.8 by WPDeveloper | Auto-updates disabled
Favethemes Insights Version 1.2.6 by Favethemes | Auto-updates disabled
Flying Scripts  Version 1.2.3 by WP Speed Matters | Auto-updates disabled
Halorumah   Version 0.0.1 by Ardi Renaldi | Auto-updates disabled
Houzez CRM  Version 1.3.3 by Favethemes | Auto-updates disabled
Houzez Login Register   Version 2.8.1 by Favethemes | Auto-updates disabled
Houzez Theme - Functionality    Version 2.8.1 by Favethemes | Auto-updates disabled
Nav Menu Roles  Version 2.1.2 by Kathy Darling | Auto-updates disabled
Pricing Table by PickPlugins    Version 1.12.9 by pickplugins | Auto-updates disabled
PRO Elements    Version 3.6.4 by PROElements.org | Auto-updates disabled
Redux Framework Version 4.4.1 by Team Redux | Auto-updates disabled
Site Kit by Google  Version 1.93.0 by Google | Auto-updates enabled
Stream  Version 3.9.3 by XWP | Auto-updates disabled
Wordfence Security  Version 7.9.2 by Wordfence | Auto-updates disabled
WPCode Lite Version 2.0.12 by WPCode | Auto-updates disabled
WP Offload Media Lite   Version 3.2.2 by Delicious Brains | Auto-updates disabled
WP Rocket   Version 3.12.3.3 by WP Media | Auto-updates disabled
Yoast SEO   Version 20.7 by Team Yoast | Auto-updates disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress core uses a user ID of zero to represent a non-authenticated user (there isn't a user account to delete). What this probably means is that user data is being changed by a non-authenticated user, or through some means that Stream is unable to identify the user making the change.

You'll likely need to research security firms and hire one to audit WordPress sites to get your site fully cleaned up and re-secured.